# Catalog Search indexer process unknown error

Tags: magento2, error, reindex, cli, wamp

I'm getting a 'One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.' and it seems I need to run php bin/magento indexer:reindex from the CLI.
I get the index rebuilt successfully on all indexes but one the ***Catalog Search***
This is the Command along with the full success and error message.

```
 PS C:\wamp64\www\magento2> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:05
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:07
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:04
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /magento2_product_1_v1.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.35 (Win64) PHP/7.2.10 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I'm using - 
magento 2 v2.3.0
wamp v3.1.4
php v7.2.10
windows 10

Comment: i guss that you nee config elastic search

Comment: I'm new to using magento - do you suggest following this documentation 'https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html'?

Answer (score 2):

Check your ElasticSearch version, it probably isn't the same selected in the Magento admin panel.

This command will help you to check the version, you might change the host.

```
curl http://elasticsearch:9200
```

```
{
  "name" : "jPBGI6O",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "eR6UbtkgSJC8zO-J6jSF2A",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.5.4",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "d2ef93d",
    "build_date" : "2018-12-17T21:17:40.758843Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.5.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

[image: Magento 2 ElasticSearch]

Answer (score 0):

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/elasticsearch.conf

=> paste this code

<VirtualHost *:8080>
ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
</VirtualHost>

sudo a2ensite elasticsearch.conf
```

[Visit this link for detailed clarification](https://www.magetop.com/blog/install-magento-2-4-2-on-ubuntu/#5_Install_Elasticsearch)